# react variabels are not showing in render, but after reload they do, what is going wrong

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, render

oke I have written the following class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import moment from 'moment';

import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';

export class ReservationListBase extends Component {
     constructor(props){
          super(props)

          this.state = {
          ...props,
          ReservationList: null,
          loading: true,
          }
      }

  componentDidMount(){
  this.props.firebase
    .reserveringen()
    .orderByChild("futureReservation")
    .equalTo(true)
    .on('value', snapshot => {

        const ReservationObject = snapshot.val()

        if(ReservationObject !== null){
          let ReservationList = Object.keys(ReservationObject).map(key => ({
              ...ReservationObject[key],
              uid: key,
          }))

          ReservationList.map((reservation, index) => {
            this.props.firebase
              .boot(reservation.bootuid)
              .on('value' , snapshot => {
                  ReservationList[index]['bootnaam'] = snapshot.val().bootnaam
                  ReservationList[index]['boottype'] = snapshot.val().boottype
              })

            this.props.firebase
              .user(reservation.useruid)
              .on('value', snapshot => {
                ReservationList[index]['username'] = snapshot.val().username
              })
          })
          console.log("after filling data")
          console.log(ReservationList)

          ReservationList = this.checkIfNotFuture(ReservationList)

          this.setState({
            ReservationList,
            loading: false,
          })

          return ReservationList
        } else {
          this.setState({
            ReservationList: [],
            loading: false,
          })

          return []
        }
      })
}

checkIfNotFuture(ReservationList){
     const now = moment()

     ReservationList.map((reservation, index) => {
           const endDate = moment(reservation.endDate)

           if(now > endDate){
                this.props.firebase
                    .reservering(reservation.uid)
                    .update({
                         futureReservation: false,
                    })

                ReservationList.splice(index, 1)
          }})

     return ReservationList
 }

 componentWillUnmount(){
      this.props.firebase
          .reserveringen()
          .orderByChild("futureReservation")
          .equalTo(true)
          .off()

      this.setState({
           ReservationList: null
      })
}

render() {
const {ReservationList, loading} = this.state

console.log("state in render")
console.log(ReservationList)

return (
  <div>
    {ReservationList &&
      <ul>
        {ReservationList.map(reservation => (
          <li key={reservation.uid}>
            <span>
              <strong>start reservering</strong> {reservation.startDate}
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>einde reservering</strong> {reservation.endDate}
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>bootnaam</strong> {reservation.bootnaam}
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>boottype</strong> { reservation.boottype }
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>gebruiker</strong> { reservation.username }
            </span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul> 
    }
    {!loading &&
    <div>
      {!ReservationList &&
        <div>
          geen reserveringen aanwezig
        </div>
      }
    </div>  
    }

    <Link to={ROUTES.RESERVERINGEN_DATETIME}>Maak Nieuwe Reservering</Link>

  </div>
)
}
}

export default ReservationListBase
```

I know it is a lot but I do not know where the problem occurs, (also sorry for some dutch names in the variabels)
It executeds with no errors, only a view warnings about no return statements from the arrow functions

the main problem is that the variabels "reservation.bootnaam" and "reservation.boottype" (you can find these in render, do not display when the list is loaded the first time, after reloading they do, but ofcourse I need them to show the first time

this class has the ability to contact with firebase with no problems

aditional information:

the console log is as following:

```
[{…}]
0:
    bootuid: "-M2iYgSUHJrEEE1C5GSB"
    endDate: "2020-04-02T21:15:00+02:00"
    futureReservation: true
    startDate: "2020-04-02T20:45:00+02:00"
    useruid: "JXPeUeF5NzgatXriREpdwcTa71W2"
    uid: "-M3ue2p3I0B-WYz5-g-p"
    username: "Harry Janssen"
    bootnaam: "aquilo"
    boottype: "4+"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
ReservationListBase.js:124 state in render
ReservationListBase.js:125 
[{…}]
    0:
    bootuid: "-M2iYgSUHJrEEE1C5GSB"
    endDate: "2020-04-02T21:15:00+02:00"
    futureReservation: true
    startDate: "2020-04-02T20:45:00+02:00"
    useruid: "JXPeUeF5NzgatXriREpdwcTa71W2"
    uid: "-M3ue2p3I0B-WYz5-g-p"
    username: "Harry Janssen"
    bootnaam: "aquilo"
    boottype: "4+"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
ReservationListBase.js:124 state in render
ReservationListBase.js:125 
[{…}]
    0:
    bootuid: "-M2iYgSUHJrEEE1C5GSB"
    endDate: "2020-04-02T21:15:00+02:00"
    futureReservation: true
    startDate: "2020-04-02T20:45:00+02:00"
    useruid: "JXPeUeF5NzgatXriREpdwcTa71W2"
    uid: "-M3ue2p3I0B-WYz5-g-p"
    username: "Ronne Timmerman"
    bootnaam: "aquilo"
    boottype: "4+"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

so from the get go it appears that the "bootnaam" and "boottype" are available from the state

Comment: Just a recommendation , always lowercase object attributes, at least first letter, first capital letter means react component in general, so ReservationList is component, reservationList is variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple methods that asynchronously load data from Firebase. In that case, you need to update the state in each of those methods, or in the last method that completes the loading. You now only set the state in the outermost loading method, which means that you set the state *before* `bootnaam`, `boottype` and `username` are loaded.

The `console.log()` is throwing you on the wrong trail here, as the Chrome JavaScript console actually updates the object as additional data is loaded. Often that is what you want, but here it's making it harder to troubleshoot. To see the object as it is when you log it, you can try:

```
  console.log("after filling data")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(ReservationList)))
```

This ensures that you print a static snapshot of the JSON at the time of the `console.log` statement.

As said, to fix the problem you'll need to call `setState` in the nested `on('value'` handlers. You can:

- either call `setState` whenever any of the data is loaded, which means that you're building up the state of the component as it comes from the database.
- or call `setState` only when you know all data is available. This means that you'll need to keep some internal state in the component for tracking this.

Since the first is simpler, I recommend going that path. This means that your rendering code needs to be able to handle the absence of the properties that are loaded asynchronously, but that in general is a good practice. Aside from that, the code would look something like:

```
  ReservationList.map((reservation, index) => {
    this.props.firebase
      .boot(reservation.bootuid)
      .on('value' , snapshot => {
          ReservationList[index]['bootnaam'] = snapshot.val().bootnaam
          ReservationList[index]['boottype'] = snapshot.val().boottype
          this.setState({
            ReservationList
          })
      })

    this.props.firebase
      .user(reservation.useruid)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        ReservationList[index]['username'] = snapshot.val().username
        this.setState({
          ReservationList
        })
      })
```

Comment: it is working, only thing that is a bit anoing is that the render function is executed 4 times now on one reservation in the database. so if I have 50 reservations it will execute's 200 times. do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Yes, that would be the second option I mentioned. You'd still move the `setState` into the nested callbacks, but only call it once all/sufficient data has loaded.

Comment: Unrelated: not sure if you expect updates to `bootnaam`, `boottype` and `value`. If not, you're going to have a lot of useless listeners with your current code, and might to switch to using `once()` instead of `on()`.